# Is it possible to secure the blazor.boot.json in Blazor WASM?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Our security provider has flagged _framework/blazor.boot.json as a security issue (low impact). This is because it's a publicly available configuration file.

The recommendation is to store configuration files outside of publicly accessible Webroot and directories to prevent direct access.

Microsoft documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

> When an app is built, the generated `blazor.boot.json` manifest describes the SHA-256 hashes of boot resources at the time that the build output is produced. The integrity check passes as long as the SHA-256 hashes in `blazor.boot.json` match the files delivered to the browser.

From my research it appears that the file must be publicly available to load the app and I can't find any information on why this would be a security risk or any ways to mitigate it.

I have made sure that the environment is set to [production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0) as advised by the security provider.

So, is it possible to secure the blazor.boot.json in Blazor WASM? and is there any security risk leaving it public?

Comment: The recommendation is for server-side apps. For Wasm (or Js/TypeScript) apps it is nonsense.

Comment: For security purposes, you should upgrade your security provider.

Comment: "From my research it appears that the file must be publicly available to load the app and I can't find any information on why this would be a security risk or any ways to mitigate it." It's not a security risk unless you put data in there that should not be public. This is no different than any other web page/app and the files they use.

Comment: blazor.boot.json is needed for the client app to understand what file is changed after latest deployment. You cannot move it outside wwwroot because the client app needs to load it at startup.